# getBufferStrategy(); or createBufferStrategy(2/3); Which comes first? And does it matter?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, jframe

I have been looking up some examples in books and in on line video's. I find that when people are creating a bufferStrategy they do it in so many different ways.

For example, as I understand it, I'm supposed to

```
 BufferStrategy bufferStrat = null;
    canvasObject.createBufferStrategy(3);
    bufferStrat = canvasObject.getBufferStrategy();
```

and then I can go ahead and do things like

```
Graphics g = bufferStrat.getDrawGraphics();
```

However, I recently saw someone do it this way (imagine that the class i'm working in extends Canvas)

```
public void render(){
BufferStrategy bufferStrat = getBufferStrategy(); //I understand that this returns a null
if(bufferStrat == null){
createBufferStrategy(3);
return;
}
Graphics g = bufferStrat.getDrawGraphics();
}
```

Can someone explain exactly what is happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is the correct usage. There's no practical reason I can think of for creating a local bufferstrategy field every time render is called.(as in the second example)

Creating a bufferstrategy and assigning it to a field (like in your first example) should only be done once, outside the render function.

Answer (score 0):

It won't get created over and over again... it only creates it once! This because if the `BufferStrategy` is not equal to null it won't create a new one. This is much used for 2D games (for example)

I rather prefer the first example either but, this is also a useful code:

```
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bufferStrat = getBufferStrategy(); //I understand that this returns a null
    if(bufferStrat == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bufferStrat.getDrawGraphics();
}
```